# Request of help for a problem on 2-forms

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, exterior-derivative

Let $y = f(x)$ and $z = g(x, y) $ be real functions of one variable $x$ and two variables $(x,y)$ respectively.  Suppose $$dz \wedge dx =0.$$
What conclusion can be drawn from this statements?

My attempt:
$$0 = dz\wedge dx =(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} dx+ \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}dy)\wedge dx = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}dy\wedge dx. $$
Can we conclude $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$ or the above statement is always true (because of that $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}dy\wedge dx = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y} \frac{\partial f}{ dx} dx\wedge dx$ and $dx\wedge dx =0$)?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Looks like $\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=0$ is what you are meant to conclude.  I do not think the function $f$ is relevant to this part of the question.

Comment: I disagree. Because you started with $y=f(x)$, I conclude that you’re talking about $z=g(x,f(x))$, in which case $dz\wedge dx$ is automatically $0$.